# How to use ffplay with -filter_complex?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i vo.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a]showcqt[out_v];[0:v]nullsink"
```

results in

```
Failed to set value '[0:a]showcqt[out_v];[0:v]nullsink' for option 'filter_complex': Option not found
```

I know about `amovie` from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FancyFilteringExamples , just trying to figure out how graphs work with `-filter_complex`.

Comment: `ffplay -f lavfi "movie=vo.mkv:s=dv+da[vid][aud];`

Comment: now I can't hear the sound.

Comment: Looks like there is just no way to output video and audio simultaniously when you use ffplay filters. Ffmpeg though can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='filename.mp4':s=dv+da[out0][out1]"
```

`out0` and `out1` are reserved labels for the ultimate output streams.

This will work as well:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='filename.mp4':s=dv+da[vid][aud];[vid]copy[out0];[aud]acopy[out1]"
```

Comment: First one works, second one says "No such filter: 'acopy'". I tried asplit before, doesn't look like it's working either.

Comment: Actually, it works now, with asplit. Yes, it's solved.

Comment: I see now. I was using [vid_out][aud_out] instead of [out0][out1]